# What are options to set up a new portable SSD for newer and legacy Windows computers?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, external-hard-drive, formatting

I bought a new 4TB M.2 NVME and an external M.2 enclosure for it. I want to set this up to be used like portable storage (used like "flash" storage), so that it can be used on a new Win 11 laptop and much older Win 10 desktop. The Win 10 desktop runs legacy BIOS.
What are my options to set up and format this new SSD, so that I can use it like it is a external "flash storage" drive, and it will work for both newer and older computers?
Detailed instructions for the different options available would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the enclosure - what is it and how does it connect to the computer? If it's USB you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: The enclosure converts a M.2 SSD into an external drive. Yes it's USB; the enclosure connects to a computer/device via USB cable. But I was under the understanding that there is a 2TB limit for legacy BIOS computers, so I don't think I can simply set it up as a 4TB drive (unless I'm wrong about that).

Comment: Choose NTFS? I am confused by what your question actually is, USB has been around, for almost any working machine that might be operating. MBR/GPT only matters on system disk with regards to Windows

Comment: There is no need to use MBR for Windows 10, unless your planning to boot from the USB device.  As long as your not planning on booting from your M.2 use GPT and windows 10 and even windows 7 will be fine.  I added 4tb gpt hdd to windows 7 PCs with legacy BIOS as a D drive and had no issues.

Answer (score 3):

> I bought a new 4TB M.2 NVME and an external M.2 enclosure for it. I want to set this up to be used like portable storage (used like "flash" storage),

It is literally "flash" storage in every sense (just a slightly more reliable type), and you can treat it as such.

With your setup, the computer doesn't even know that it uses NVMe as the interface – the enclosure's controller translates between that and USB "Mass Storage" SCSI, so it appears as a removable device and works for all intents and purposes like a very large USB stick. (This means the OS doesn't even need an NVMe driver to talk to it.)

> The Win 10 desktop runs legacy BIOS.

That's irrelevant. It's a data disk, not an OS disk – the system firmware never interacts with it at all.

> What are my options to set up and format this new SSD, so that I can use it like it is a external "flash storage" drive,

The only real difference from USB flash drives is that MBR and FAT32 are usually no longer an option at this capacity (which rules out WinXP and some smart TVs) – once you go beyond 2TB, GPT and NTFS/exFAT are the remaining choices for partitioning and filesystem (formatting) respectively.

(Unless your enclosure plays dirty tricks with sector sizes...as is commonly done by SATA enclosures. Such tricks allow MBR and FAT32 usage but make the disk dependent on the enclosure. Alternatively, I believe that *technically* MBR usage is possible for up to 4TB with two 2TB partitions, but you probably don't need this.)

Other than that – treat it like a regular internal disk and/or USB stick (not much of a practical difference). Initialize it as a GPT, create one large partition, format it as exFAT (or NTFS). The system will handle it as removable because it sees it as a USB drive, regardless of the filesystem.

exFAT may have better compatibility with TVs and such devices, as it's the new "official" filesystem for large flash drives and SD cards. On the other hand, NTFS may recover better from crashes.

(If you choose to use NTFS, go to "Properties - Security" and add 'Everyone' with full access.)

> and it will work for both newer and older computers?

Depends on how old you mean by "older". For the purposes of this question, Windows 10 is not old – Windows XP is old, whereas all releases starting with Vista have nearly identical capabilities to Windows 11.

(Again, this is partly due to the USB "Mass Storage" devices using a standard interface – your enclosure deals with NVMe so your OS doesn't have to, so that difference can be safely ignored.)

Only the pre-Vista releases differ significantly:

- Partition table: Windows XP was the last release that lacked GPT support (in the usual variants) and only spoke MBR. Starting with Vista, GPT is supported everywhere.

  Unlike for boot volumes, the PC's firmware is completely irrelevant here – the only code that looks at the partition table of a data disk is the OS itself.
- Partition count: Okay, so there *is* a difference between Windows Vista/7/8 and Windows 10/11. If the enclosure reports itself as a truly "Removable" device (like a USB stick or a SD card would), then pre-Win10 systems only support one partition. But usually that's what you want for a portable "flash" device anyway – one large partition that covers the entire disk.

  (If I remember correctly, multiple partitions would work on enclosures that report themselves as a non-removable disk... but starting with Windows 10.15xx or such, they work on all kinds.)
- Filesystem: XP has built-in support for NTFS (which hasn't changed *much* since), but exFAT support can be installed as an official update.

  Not that it matters much in this case, as 32-bit XP can't understand GPT anyway so you'd need a smaller disk (or one of those enclosures that lie about sectors).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent and detailed answer. I read that I'm supposed to mark this post as "the answer", but I don't see the function/button to do so.